# exit not working as expected in Bash

Tags: bash, ssh

I use SSH Secure Shell client to connect to a server and run my scripts.

I want to stop a script on some conditions, so when I use exit, not only the script stops, but all the client disconnects from the server!, Here is the code:

```
if [[ `echo $#` -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "Missing argument- must to get a friend list";
        exit
fi

for user in $*; do
        if [[ !(-f `echo ${user}.user`) ]]; then
                echo "The user name ${user} doesn't exist.";
                exit
        fi
done
```

A picture of the client:
[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: You can use the variable values directly without calling `echo` from inside a pair of backticks; just `if [[ $? -eq 0]];` and `if [[ ! -f "$user.user" ]]` should work fine.

Comment: Use `for user in "$@"` instead of `for user in $*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `source` to run the script, this runs it in the current shell. That means that `exit` terminates the current shell and with that the ssh session.

replace `source` with  `bash` and it should work, or better put

```
#!/bin/bash
```

on to of the file and make it executable.

Answer (score 2):

`exit` returns from the current **shell** - If you've started a script by running it directly, this will exit the shell that the script is running in.

`return` returns from a **function** or **sourced file** (TY Dennis Williamson) - Same thing, but it doesn't terminate your current shell.

`break` returns from a **loop** - Similar to `return`, but can be used anywhere within a loop to stop processing more items. This is probably what you want.

Comment: +1 - `return` will also accept a return value.
`builtin help return`
`builtin help exit`

Answer (score 0):

if you are running from the current shell, exit will obviously exit from the shell and disconnect you. try running it in a new shell ( use a . before the script) or else use 'return' instead of exit

Comment: `.` before the script does the same as `source`. And `return` can only be used from within a funcion.

Comment: @mata: See `help return`: "Causes a function or *sourced script* to exit"

Comment: @DennisWilliamson - Oh, tanks. It even says so if you type 'return' in bash: `can only 'return' from a function or sourced script`... should at least have tried that.